# Listbox item trigger colour change

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to change the colour of the items in a listbox based on a trigger using MVVM

```
 <Border Grid.Row="1" Width="300" Margin="0,0,20,0" BorderThickness="1,2,1,1" CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="#FF999393" Background="#FFE9EDF1" >
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding LogMessageList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Background="{x:Null}" Margin="3" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" FontSize="13.333" >
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
             <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF403E3E" />
                  <Style.Triggers>
                       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FatalError, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Value="Fatal">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Firebrick" />
                       </DataTrigger>
                  </Style.Triggers>
             </Style>
         </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>                                                       
  </ListBox>
```

I'm setting the property change correctly but nothing seems to change.

Thanks

EDIT:
Still stuck. Trying

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF403E3E" />
           <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}},Path=DataContext.FatalError, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Value="Fatal">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Firebrick" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Is there any binding failure logged in output windows? Is `FatalError` property defined in Model used for LogMessageList collection? If yes, can you please validate that `PropertyChanged` event is notified by setter.

Comment: Good call. Looks like as I am using the target type listboxitem then the binding is looking at the items in the list and not my 'global' property on the viewmodel. Figuring out now.

Comment: You can use RelativeSource to bind your global property of your viewmodel.

Comment: Can you help with the above edit and I will marked as answered too. Thanks so much for help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried your scenario. Please refer the below code example:

**View Model**

```
public class Vm : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<VmUser> VmUsers { get; set; }

    private string errorType;

    public string ErrorType
    {
        get { return errorType; }
        set 
        {
             errorType = value;
             Raise("ErrorType");
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void Raise(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

public class VmUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Set the `DataContext` of window in constructor :

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        Vm = new Vm
        {
            VmUsers = new ObservableCollection<VmUser>
            {
                new VmUser { Name = "Gil", Age = 1 },
                new VmUser { Name = "Dan", Age = 2 },
                new VmUser { Name = "John", Age = 3 },
            },

            ErrorType = "Fatal"
        };
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = TheVm;
    }
```

Defined `ListBox` in XAML as:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding VmUsers}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Age">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF403E3E" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}},Path=DataContext.ErrorType, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Value="Fatal">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
```

To test the scenario I have wrote a small test to toggle the ErrorType on click on button

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var vm = this.DataContext as Vm;
    if (vm != null)
    {
        if (vm.ErrorType  == "Fatal")
        {
            vm.ErrorType = "Non Fatal";
        }
        else
        {
            vm.ErrorType = "Fatal";
        }
    }
}
```

With above example foreground color changes based on ErrorType.

Comment: Wow that was longwinded. Thanks so much for your help on this. I actually couldnt get it working until I changed the AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}. Really appreciated.

Comment: Note: I was in a userControl. So that would have worked.

Comment: Thanks scottsanpedro. But I am not sure, how to set as an answer to provided answer.

Comment: I have ticked, so hopefully that has given you the credit.

Comment: Yes, in case if there are properties which are not part of DataContext of ListBox then you can set the Ancestore Type to UserContorl.